# getting image from ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I've got a custom field set up using Advanced Custom Fields - the field is named "Company Logo" and is an image field which is returning an image url. I've tried the array and the image ID but nothing seems to work.

I'm attempting to use `<img src="[acf field='company_logo']">`

however it fails and displays

`<img src="[acf field='company_logo']">`

in the page source - no idea how to get it to actually show the correct info.
Any ideas how to get it to show the image?

Comment: where are you placing that code?

Comment: You can’t use shortcodes inside attributes.

Comment: So I'm running Ultimate Members, I have a page set as "Profile Page" and on that I'm pulling out the infomation - there is a section where I can add shortcodes or content block. I've tried to use the shortcode directly but that doesn't show it - so I added the above in the content block.

If I add <img src="http://test.com/test.jpg" alt="test image" />
then it works fine, I'm trying to do the same with the output of the field for company_logo.

Answer (score 1):

you can get ACF image in three ways of return type, see below:-

1] Image return type : ID [ **Image ID** return type ]

```
<?php 
$image = get_field('image'); //acf field name
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}
```

2] Image return type : Array  [ **Image Object** return type ]

```
<?php 
$image = get_field('image'); //acf field name
if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

3] Image return type : URL [ **Image URL** return type ]

```
<?php 
$image = get_field('image');
if( get_field('image') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. As other said, you can't mix shortcode in the HTML attributes.

You'll need to edit the Ultimate Members PHP template. Check in their doc how to edit them in a child theme to not lose them on Ultimate Member update.

You will need to make something like:

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'the_field' ){
?>
    <img src="<?php the_field( 'company_logo' );?>">
<?php
}
```